# When creating a universal application, how to link to a framework with separated 32bit and 64bit version?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, linker, 32bit-64bit

My situation:

- I want to create a universal application of i386 and x86_64 in Xcode 3.2.2
- This application has a dependent third-party framework.
- This framework only has separated versions for i386 and x86_64, no universal version.
- I added both of the i386 and x86_64 versions into the `Link Binary With Libraries` section of my target.

My problem:

Xcode cannot find symbols from the framework when building a x86_64 version. Looks like Xcode only search symbols in the i386 version of framework, by command line arguments "-framework $FRAMEWORK_NAME".

My question:

How could I make Xcode also search symbols from the x86_64 framework? Or is it possible to link to a non-universal library when building a universal application?

My progress:

I guess that creating a universal version of this framework by `lipo` maybe solves this problem, but if possible, I would like to avoid this. Because it involves some external changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two versions of your app and `lipo` them together, but it's probably easiest if you just `lipo` the framework itself. There's no reason you need to affect the external library's build process; you can just do it in place as part of the build process for your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could link two separate versions of your app, and the join those with lipo.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the framework to build fat (or `lipo`ing together the two slices) is by far the most elegant solution.  Is there a reason to not do that?